# Problems with File Download via VB Script

Tags: vbscript, stream, download, request, call

Somebody asked me to write a script, that downloads a csv file and save it to the local disk.
The csv is located on a PLC Controller that has an integrated webserver. You can communicate via IP with the PLC and get the files manually. But the customer wants to download it automatically.

I wrote the following function:

```
Function DownloadFile(strURL)

    Dim oStream
    Dim strSaveTo

    strSaveTo = strLocalPath & "\" & strFilename

    'HTTP Request abschicken
    oHTTP.Open "GET",strURL
    oHTTP.Send()

    If oHTTP.Status = 200 Then  
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  

        With oStream
            .Type = 1   'adTypeBinary
            .Open                       
            .Write oHTTP.ResponseBody   
            .SaveToFile strSaveTo       
            .Close                      
        End With
        set oStream = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

It worked with my test site, but not with the PLC.
I know why:

On my testsite the path was like this: ip/folder/file.csv
But on PLC you call the file parametrized via HTML : ip/htmlPage.html?file=c.csv

Now the answer of the request is not the csv file, its the html page...

How can I get the csv File using the parametrized Path?

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Parametrized requests should work just fine. You should run the request synchronously, though (`oHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False`), and I'd also recommend including the protocol with `strURL` (`http://ip/htmlPage.html?file=c.csv`). Also, check if the output you're getting contains some kind of redirection to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile()`?
Example:

```
Function DownloadFile(strURL)

    Dim strSaveTo
    strSaveTo = strLocalPath & "\" & strFilename
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(strURL, strSaveTo)

End Function
```

You can add parameters for the get request in the normal URL way: `http://somerequest.com/?parameter=cool`
More information to the `DownloadFile()` method can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)